# Is "Tomorrow's" equal to "tomorrow is"?

Tags: grammar

Can I use 'tomorrow's' 'instead of 'tomorrow is'?

E.g. Tomorrow's your exam.

Is such a contraction allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we commonly contract proper nouns with *'s* to mean *is* or *has*. Contracted nouns are part of everyday speech, and while some of these kinds of contractions are less common in written English than in conversation, prose in literature is often written to mimic everyday speech. Resources for learning English sometimes provide non-exhaustive lists of 'common' English contractions using pronouns. Of course, you could not expect to find every proper noun listed with its contraction.

Context would be needed to determine the meaning of the contraction. "*Tomorrow's*" could also be used as a possessive noun.

Comment: The contraction "tomorrow's" is used to mean "tomorrow is" _all the time_. Just search for "tomorrow's going to" to find all manner of examples.

Comment: It's impossible to accurately judge how someone will parse "tomorrow's" without any surrounding context. In that aspect, I feel that this answer is therefore unfounded. Secondly, how would this be any different from any other words where the possessive and the contraction of "is" is spelled the same way? People are not getting confused by the difference between "Bob's uncle is happy" and "Bob's happy", so why should they be getting confused by "Tomorrow's weather will be sunny" and "Tomorrow's going to be sunny"?

Comment: @psmears My last paragraph covered this - that you will find it written that way in imitation of speech. The examples you speak of are exactly that. But it isn't a *common* contraction and without context could not be recognised. You wouldn't find it described in a scholarly dictionary that way.

Comment: @Astralbee: My point is that it very much _is_ a common contraction, and will certainly be recognised. And it is mentioned [in the dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/s?q=%27s) - it says "short form of *is*".

Comment: In my experience "tomorrow's" for "tomorrow is" is very common in speech. However Google ngram shows "tomorrow's going" to be much less used than "tomorrow is going" in written material.

Comment: @psmears I think you're getting confused. 'Common contractions' are like 'common toads'. You don't get to decide that another kind of toad is a common toad just because you see it often. 'Common contractions' are ones using pronouns,  like "isn't" or "she'll", and these are so common they are often taught to English learners. You couldn't make a list of contractions with proper nouns.

Comment: @Astralbee: I'm pretty sure I'm not the one confusing contractions with toads :) Where is your list of Official Common Contractions that doesn't include "'s" as a contraction of "is"? Certainly every list I've found includes it. And using "'s" for "is" following "tomorrow" is no less common than anywhere else.